# how to pass class parameter through Rotativa.ActionAsPdf

Tags: model-view-controller, rotativa

I want to pass class parameter in ActionAsPdf

```
public ActionResult Pdf(long Id)
    {
        var printclass = this._printService.GetPrintResults(Id);

      return new ActionAsPdf("Content", new {Id = Id})
     {
      FileName = "abc.pdf"
      }
    }

    public ActionResult Content(long Id)
    {
    //viewModel
     return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
```

It's working fine if Id alone is passed. But I want the printclass (var printclass of type class) to be passed in as the parameter as well to the Content.

I am having problem when I try to pass the class like below.

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Content", new {Id = Id, printclass= printclass})
         {
          FileName = "abc.pdf"
          }


public ActionResult Content(long Id, printDTO abc)
        {
            var temp = abc;
        //viewModel
         return View("Index", viewModel);
        }
```

The value of temp is null in the above case.

Comment: I don't have any problems passing a viewmodel to another action using Rotativa. Is there an error message? Can you show your code when trying to pass a viewmodel

Comment: I tried to pass in the class through tempData and Session but I am getting null values in there

Comment: @Rama did you find a workaround? I am struggling with and getting totally desperate...

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewAsPdf() instead. ActionAsPdf() accepts a RouteValueDictionary parameter.